# Invalid variable name error in QB64 with old QuickBasic code

Tags: qbasic, qb64, quickbasic

I am trying to run a `QuickBasic` file written by someone else in 1992.  I am using `QB64` on a `Windows 10` machine.  I get an error message that says `Invalid variable name` in `line 26` of the following code.  `Lines 1-31` are below, but here is `line 26` in isolation.

```
COMMON SHARED /rgraph/ absxmin(), absymin(), absxmax(), absymax()
```

I tried changing the names of `absxmin()`, `absymin()`, `absxmax()`, `absymax()` to various things but the error message always appeared.  Then I tried removing `line 26` and I got the same error message for the next line.

```
COMMON SHARED /rgraph/ uxmin(), uymin(), uxmax(), uymax(), shrinkl(), shrinkr()
```

Here are `lines 1-31`.  When people use the code, which came with a book, people are asked to attribute it.  So, the code was written by Ray Hilborn, I believe.

```
DECLARE SUB zGraphInit (ScreenNumber#)
DECLARE SUB zLabelX (ig!, label$)
DECLARE SUB zLabelY (ig!, ylabel$)
DECLARE SUB hess (popt#(), h#(), r#(), sigma#, npar!, npts!, lu!)
DECLARE SUB CallFlet ()
DECLARE SUB UserPlot (itn!, f#, n!, x#())
DECLARE SUB zClearTotalScreen ()
DECLARE SUB waitsub ()
DECLARE SUB InitGraphs ()
DECLARE SUB zGrid (ig!, xtics#, ytics#)
DECLARE SUB zCursor (ig!, x#, y#, irow!, icol!)
DECLARE SUB zScale (ig!, axs#, ays#, axl#, ayl#, uxs#, uys#, uxl#, uyl#, shl#, shr#)
DECLARE SUB mnmx (x#(), n!, xmin#, xmax#)
DECLARE SUB zGraphView (ig!)
DECLARE SUB flet (f#, x#(), n!, g#(), h#(), dfn#, xm#(), hh#, eps#, mode!, maxfn!, iprint!, w#(), iexit!)
DECLARE FUNCTION func# (x#(), n!)
DECLARE SUB printstats (xtime#, itn!, ifn!, f#, n!, x#(), g#())
DECLARE FUNCTION NormDev! ()
DECLARE FUNCTION xmed# (x#(), n!)
DECLARE SUB zLocate (irow!, icol!)
DECLARE SUB InputData ()
DEFDBL A-H, O-Z

DIM absxmin(10), absymin(10), absxmax(10), absymax(10), absperux(10), absperuy(10)
DIM uxmin(10), uymin(10), uxmax(10), uymax(10), shrinkl(10), shrinkr(10)
COMMON SHARED /rgraph/ absxmin(), absymin(), absxmax(), absymax()
COMMON SHARED /rgraph/ uxmin(), uymin(), uxmax(), uymax(), shrinkl(), shrinkr()
COMMON SHARED /rgraph/ screenxdots, screenydots, absperux(), absperuy()

COMMON SHARED IprintResid, iprint, Idebug
```

Thank you for any help in resolving this error message.

Comment: [_The COMMON block name designates a certain block of variables that certain program modules may use, the name must be within two forward slashes/ (Ex: /thename/ ). Not supported in QB64_](http://qb64.org/wiki/COMMON_SHARED).  Sounds to me like you need to stick with QuickBASIC in a DOS emulator or modify the code to avoid `COMMON SHARED`.

Comment: It might have worked if you'd simply removed the slashed name.  COMMON SHARED was probably supported but qb64 probably had no idea what to do with the named share.  I knew of that feature but never used it in my DOS apps, I only used COMMON SHARED alone.  There must be some other code that is being called that also has those named shared common variables, too, though, that are probably attached link-time.

Answer (score 1):

A friend told me how to get the `QBasic` file running.  Here are his instructions slightly edited.  Essentially you need to install an `MS-DOS emulator` and a version of `QBasic`, here `QB45`.  Some of the following is specific to the file in my original post, but the instructions can probably be generalized to many old `QBasic` files.

1. Download an `MS-DOS` emulator (`DOSBOX`, https://sourceforge.net/projects/dosbox/files/latest/download)
2. Download a version of `QBASIC` (https://www.qbasic.net/en/qbasic-downloads/DOS/Windows-Solutions.htm).  (I downloaded the first of the two suggested solutions: `Basic 2 DOSBox`)
3. Install `dosbox`, but when it asks where to install it, put it in `c:\pgms\dosbox` (not `c:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.74-3`). The old `ms-dos` operating system doesn’t like long filenames or filenames with spaces in them.)
4. Paste the `QB45` folder (obtained when unzipping the file in Step 2) in `c:\pgms\dosbox\`
5. Locate `dosbox.exe` (from Step 1) and double-click it.  That should open a black window with a prompt, `Z:\>`.
6. In that window, type `mount c c:\pgms\dosbox`.
7. Also type `mount d c:\users\mark_\disk` where `chap11` is a `subfolder` in that `folder`. The folder `disk` and the `subfolder chap11` are specific to the `QBasic` file in my original post.
8. Type `d:`
9. Type `cd chap11`
10. Type `c:\qb45\qb d:\chap11\catch1.mak`

That should load `qbasic` with the `CATCH1.BAS` and 3 other basic programs needed.  The program `CATCH1.BAS` will be displayed on the screen.

11. Run the program by hitting `Alt-R`, `Enter`.